# Extracting variables while reading in data files

Tags: matlab

I am quite new to data analysis, so if this is a rookie question, I'm sorry, I am learning as I go.

I have just started doing some work in variable star astronomy. I have about 100 files for every night of observation that all contain the same basic information (star coordinates, magnitude, etc.). I am loading all of the files into my workspace as arrays using a for-loop

```
files = dir('*.out');

for i=1:length(files)
eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);
end
```

I'm only really interested in two columns in each file. Is there a way to extract a column and set it to a vector while this for-loop is running? I'm sure that it's possible, but the actual syntax for it is escaping me.

Comment: Just a comment: why use `eval(...)` when you can directly call `load(files(i).name, '-ascii')`?

Comment: I'll try doing that, I'm using eval because it was what the Mathworks resources I was reading told me to do, and then it worked. I'll try it your way, though, and see if my problem is more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `load` as a function and save it's output to a variable

```
files = dir('*.out');
twoCols = {};
for ii=1:length(files)
    data = load( files(ii).name, '-ascii' ); % load file into "data"
    twoCols{ii} = data(:,1:2); % take only two columns 
end
```

Now variable `twoCols` holds the two columns of each file in a different cell.

Comment: Ok, this is mostly working, and what I'm looking for. However, my iterations seem to be getting stuck at around i=37, where data suddenly has the dimensions of [0,0]. I can't find anything wrong in my data, though.

Comment: @Ryan corrupted file? an empty set?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, I'll just have to keep experimenting.

Comment: Can you open the problematic file in an editor? is it possible it has empty rows? @Ryan

Comment: I opened it in Notebook++, everything that was supposed to be there was there. I'll try it with another data set later.

Comment: is the problematic file identical in structure to working files? no extra lines/ spaces ? missing columns?

Comment: @Ryan if your data files are in text, you may use other functions to read them like `textread` etc. these function might be less restrictive (in terms of format) than `load -ascii`

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the load result to a new variable. Then if lets say your variable is `starsInfo` you can use

```
onlyTwoFirst = starsInfo(:,1:2)
```

That means take all the rows, but only columns 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a little trouble implementing this, though I do understand the (:,#) method. Is there a way to implement this into the for loop I used to load everything? This is how I'm trying to use your advice:

`files = dir('*.out');`


`for i=1:length(files)`
`load(files(i).name, '-ascii');`
`mag = files(i).name(:,7);`
`end`

That's not giving me a mag variable when I call my script in my workspace, unsurprisingly. My main problem is still how to pull the data from every single starsInfo file at once.

*Sorry for the formatting